# Фон блока не растягивается вместе с контентом самого блока. Помогите

Tags: css, html, background, style

У меня проблема с дивом "brya", я задаю ему background и все вроде бы хорошо, но фон не растягивается вместе с контентом который внутри дива, было пару способов, но они корявые и мне не нравятся.
Помогите!

---

```
    <tbody>
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="brya">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 100%;" id="brya1">
        <h2>Фердинанд</h2>
        <img src="../img/ferd.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="260">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 100%;" id="brya2">
        <li>год</li>
        <li>год</li>
        <li>год</li>
        <li>год</li>
        <li>год</li>
        <li>год</li>
        <li>год</li>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.brya {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: url(http://i39.tinypic.com/28i18k6.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#brya1,
#brya2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 14px;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="brya">

  <div id="brya1">
    <h2>Фердинанд</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="brya2">
    <li>год</li>
    <li>год</li>
    <li>год</li>
    <li>год</li>
    <li>год</li>
    <li>год</li>
    <li>год</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По изображению девушки я сразу вижу, кто автор данного кода....аахаах

Comment: Хаххаах смешно.